# iOS: Creating NavigationController lightbox on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, lightbox

I have been looking at different iPad apps on the market. Yelp for example has the following screen:

[image: Yelp iPad App]

Basically, this light box (log in) pops up from the bottom and "hover" over the `UISplitViewController` on the background.

How do one create this "light box" and animate it in. I am sure there is a non hacky way of doing this, just cannot find anything in my extended knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
navController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 500);
```